# How to find all words in a string that begin with an uppercase letter, for multiple strings in a list

Tags: python, regex, string, findall, capitalization

I have a list of strings, each string is about 10 sentences. I am hoping to find all words from each string that begin with a capital letter. Preferably after the first word in the sentence. I am using re.findall to do this. When I manually set the string = '' I have no trouble do this, however when I try to use a for loop to loop over each entry in my list I get a different output.

```
for i in list_3:
    string = i
    test = re.findall(r"(\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b)", string)
print(test)
```

output:

```
['I', 'I', 'As', 'I', 'University', 'Illinois', 'It', 'To', 'It', 'I', 'One', 'Manu', 'I', 'I', 'Once', 'And', 'Through', 'I', 'I', 'Most', 'Its', 'The', 'I', 'That', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I']
```

When I manually input the string value

```
txt = 0
for i in list_3:
    string = list_3[txt]
    test = re.findall(r"(\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b)", string)
print(test)
```

output:

```
['Remember', 'The', 'Common', 'App', 'Do', 'Your', 'Often', 'We', 'Monica', 'Lannom', 'Co', 'Founder', 'Campus', 'Ventures', 'One', 'Break', 'Campus', 'Ventures', 'Universities', 'Undermatching', 'Stanford', 'Yale', 'Undermatching', 'What', 'A', 'Yale', 'Lannom', 'There', 'During', 'Some', 'The', 'Lannom', 'That', 'It', 'Lannom', 'Institutions', 'University', 'Chicago', 'Boston', 'College', 'These', 'Students', 'If', 'Lannom', 'Recruiting', 'Elite', 'Campus', 'Ventures', 'Understanding', 'Campus', 'Ventures', 'The', 'For', 'Lannom', 'What', 'I', 'Wish', 'I', 'Knew', 'Before', 'Starting', 'Company', 'I', 'Even', 'I', 'Lannom', 'The', 'There']
```

But I can't seem to write a for loop that correctly prints the output for each of the 5 items in the list. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way yo do that is to write a `for` loop which checks whether the first letter of an element of the list is capitalized. If it is, it will be appended to the `output` list.

```
output = []
for i in list_3:
    if i[0] == i[0].upper():
        output.append(i)
print(output)
```

We can also use the list comprehension and made that in 1 line. We are also checking whether the first letter of an element is the capitalized letter.

```
output = [x for x in list_3 if x[0].upper() == x[0]]
print(output)
```

**EDIT**

You want to place the sentence as an element of a list so here is the solution. We iterate over the `list_3`, then iterate for every word by using the `split()` function. We are thenchecking whether the word is capitalized. If it is, it is added to an `output`.

```
list_3 = ["Remember your college application process? The tedious Common App applications, hours upon hours of research, ACT/SAT, FAFSA, visiting schools, etc. Do you remember who helped you through this process? Your family and guidance counselors perhaps, maybe your peers or you may have received little to no help"]
output = []
for i in list_3:
    for j in i.split():
        if j[0].isupper():
            output.append(j)
print(output)
```

Comment: can just do `if x[0].isupper()`

Comment: When I tried running this code, instead of the words containing uppercase letters being printed the entire content of the string was printed. Do I need to append i.upper?

Comment: @AndrewLittle1 can you show me the `input`? I thought you are giving to it single words.

Comment: The input is a string of sentences, like such "Remember your college application process? The tedious Common App applications, hours upon hours of research, ACT/SAT, FAFSA, visiting schools, etc. Do you remember who helped you through this process? Your family and guidance counselors perhaps, maybe your peers or you may have received little to no help'. Each element in list_3 is a string containing several sentences, there are five elements in list.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is the correct answer, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @AndrewLittle1 no problem, I am glad that it is working for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming sentences are separated by one space, you could use `re.findall` with the following regular expression.

```
r'(?m)(?<!^)(?<![.?!] )[A-Z][A-Za-z]*'
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/zVUgtn/3/) | [Python code](http://tpcg.io/EHTSHzci)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?m)         : set multiline mode so that ^ and $ match the beginning
               and the end of a line
(?<!^)       : negative lookbehind asserts current location is not
               at the beginning of a line
(?<![.?!] )  : negative lookbehind asserts current location is not
               preceded by '.', '?' or '!', followed by a space
[A-Z]        : match an uppercase letter
[A-Za-z]*    : match 1+ letters
```

If sentences can be separated by one or two spaces, insert the negative lookbehind `(?<![.?!]  )` after `(?<![.?!] )`.

If the PyPI regex module were used, one could use the variable-length lookbehind `(?<![.?!] +)`

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you have list like this:

```
list_3 = [
  'First sentence. Another Sentence',
  'And yet one another. Sentence',
]
```

You are iterating over the list but every iteration overrides `test` variable, thus you have incorrect result. You eihter have to accumulate result inside additional variable or print it right away, every iteration:

```
acc = []
for item in list_3:
  acc.extend(re.findall(regexp, item))
print(acc)
```

or

```
for item in list_3:
  print(re.findall(regexp, item))
```

As for regexp, that ignores first word in the sentence, you can use

```
re.findall(r'(?<!\A)(?<!\.)\s+[A-Z]\w+', s)
```

- `(?<!\A)` - not the beginning of the string
- `(?<!\.)` - not the first word after dot
- `\s+` - optional spaces after dot.

You'll receive words potentialy prefixed by space, so here's final example:

```
acc = []
for item in list_3:
  words = [w.strip() for w in re.findall(r'(?<!\A)(?<!\.)\s+[A-Z]\w+', item)]
  acc.extend(words)
print(acc)
```

Comment: Note that you are matching not just capitalized words, but also the spaces that precede them (which can be easily removed, of course).

Answer (score 0):

as I really like regexes, try this one:

```
#!/bin/python3
import re

PATTERN = re.compile(r'[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*')

all_sentences = [
    "My House! is small",
    "Does Annie like Cats???"
]

def flat_list(sentences):
    for sentence in sentences:
        yield from PATTERN.findall(sentence)

upper_words = list(flat_list(all_sentences))
print(upper_words)

# Result: ['My', 'House', 'Does', 'Annie', 'Cats']
```